# How to get the file name from the full path of the file, in vc++?

Tags: visual-c++

I need to get the name of a file from its full path, in vc++. How can I get this? I need only the file name. Can I use Split method to get this? If not how can I get the file name from the full path of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String^ fileName = "C:\\mydir\\myfile.ext";
String^ path = "C:\\mydir\\";
String^ result;
result = Path::GetFileName( fileName );
Console::WriteLine( "GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result );
```

See  [Path::GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx#Y684)

Comment: I cannot hard code the file name. It changes. Then how can I give path like this.

Comment: Who told you to hardcode .Above is just a kickoff example , you can modify it as you need .

Answer (score 0):

Find the last `\` or `/`<sup>1</sup> using one of the standard library string/`char *` search methods. Then extract the following text. Remember to special case where the `/` or `\` is the last character.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Windows API, for most purposes<sup>2</sup> supports both.

<sup>1</sup> The exception is when using long paths starting `\\?\` to break 260 character limit on paths.

Answer (score 0):

[Directory::GetFiles Method (String, String)
Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.